# grafana alert showing {} in output, from where we get this and is there anyway to update it

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-alerts

Below image shows output {} , why we get this and how to update it?
[image]

Comment: You will need to provide more details to get some help with that. Start with adding the message template you used to get that output.

Comment: sum(kube_pod_status_phase{namespace="xyz",phase="Pending"}

Comment: That looks like a Promotheus query. What is the template of the message that is sent to (what looks like) Microsoft Teams? Did you leave it empty?
Also, what version of garfana are you using? Grafana 8 has an alerting system quite different that older versions.